# Unable to print transform.parent.name

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get the name of the parent so that I can determine which button is pressed. However, it gives me:

The referenced script (Unknown) on this Behaviour is missing! Although all the names of the files are the same as the name of the class.

```
using System.Collections;

public class Buttons : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log(transform.parent.name);
    }
    
}
```

Edit: After running it twice, a new error appeared:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
> Buttons.Start () (at Assets/Buttons.cs:8)

Comment: @nccsbim071 That's not how Unity works. A Monobehaviour instance will always have a transform.

Comment: @DeathWarrior990, try including "using UnityEngine;" at the top.

Comment: What if the object has no parent?

Comment: If you can't be sure an object will be non-null, you should first check it before you reference a member of that object: `Transform p = transform.parent; if (p != null) Debug.Log(p.name);`

Comment: @Ruzihm in general you shouldn't use `!= null` though .. usually best in Unity would be `if(transform.parent) Debug.Log(transform.parent.name);` or in your example `if(p) ...` ;)

Answer (score -2):

Try `Debug.Log(gameObject.transform.parent.name)` as in following code in https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-transform.html

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        gameObject.transform.Translate(1, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

Also checkout https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html.

Comment: Going through the additional reference of the `gameObject` or directly through `transform` makes no difference whatsoever. Also the translate is completely unrelated to OPs question .. the issue is rather that there simply is no parent ...